# How to reverse: cmd attrib -s -h -r /s /d *.*. and hit Enter

Tags: batch-file, attributes

Can I run something that makes sure all of my folder Attributes are at the default settings?

I did something I didn't want to, based on this page . . . Windows command-line command to list hidden folders . . . https://superuser.com/questions/277379/windows-command-line-command-to-list-hidden-folders

I was trying to figure out if there were any errors in what my bat file was doing.

To get the output, I thought I should go to the "Startup" folder in cmd.exe, which is hidden, and run: Startup.bat > testlog.txt 2> testerrors.txt

To get there, I would have to un-hide some folders.

I found the above page, and ran the attrib command with those switches.

I think I did this in the C:\ProgramData folder (normally hidden)

I think that I put this in an elevated command prompt, based on the second answer . . . attrib -s -h -r /s /d *.*. and hit Enter

Maybe I just put this in . . . attrib -s -h -r /s /d

I thought, I'll just go fast and not think, nothing can happen . . . then, of course, I read on that same page, also, that this can alter your folder attributes . . . they should preface that with the word "CAUTION."

I think I did see a lot of "NOT ACCESSIBLE . . . " flashing by . . . it was doing something.

Is there any way to tell if I altered my folder attributes or not?

---

Does this fix I have at the bottom fix it, or not?

Quick way to reset all security permissions to default? (Windows 7)

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/d09a393b-68df-43de-9f31-735f83242497/quick-way-to-reset-all-security-permissions-to-default-windows-7?forum=w7itprosecurity&ppud=4

"Just run in a elevated prompt the following command."

secedit /configure /cfg %windir%\inf\defltbase.inf /db defltbase.sdb /verbose

This did something, but, how can I tell if it did what I want, and things are back to normal? I don't know if secedit applies to folder attributes or not.

Is there a program that puts them back at the default values . . . Is that the function of the secedit command?

Comment: Yes, you could do something. Restore a backup of your entire hard disk drive from an image backup. You don't have an image backup? Then you really have a large problem. Restoring the security settings won't change anything on file/directory attributes. Well, if you have another computer configured nearly the same as your computer, you could run both computers `attrib C:\ProgramData\* /D /S >"%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\AttribList.txt"`, compare the two text files created on desktop listing all files and folders with all attributes and then set the attributes on your computer according to other list.

Comment: I make a couple of clones with Clonezilla once per month . . . I determined that the fix, in this case, was to just replace the C: drive with one of those. It was only about 20 days old, and I had made no significant software changes.  I keep all my data files on a separate, secondary D: drive.

Answer (score 0):

> Can I run something that makes sure all of my folder attributes are at
> the default settings?

Yes and no.

No, you can't run a command from command prompt to reverse the changes you made. The command you used removed all of the following attributes/flags from all files on your entire hard drive:

- system (-s)
- hidden (-h)
- read-only (-r)

There's no way to undo this (except a system restore, if available). The reverse of the command would apply the aforementioned attributes to all files, including your data files, which is not what you want.

I suppose it is technically possible to manually re-apply all the correct attributes to each individual file, but it obviously isn't feasible.

System Restore or Image Backup.